# Debug Windows forms application for Windows 10 tablet

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows forms application works on any device having Windows 10 installed, nevertheless since I am going to deploy my windows forms app to PC and laptop users I would like to make sure it will correctly scale on tablet device.

Is there any Windows 10 tablet emulator that I could use to check application look and feel during debug or how you do it?

Comment: is [this](https://i.imgur.com/tNcvJ0F.png) not sufficient?

Comment: Not sure i need to use also GPS and on my laptop there no gps

Comment: Emulator would have GPS..

Answer (score 0):

The typical scenario for this is using virtual machines (VirtualBox, etc) with a Windows 10 image that reflects your final hardware and software as closely as possible.

It is however *not* the final hardware and there is usually no way of knowing whether it will work on the production hardware without testing it on production hardware.

You will also need to know the production hardware settings like is it using high DPI settings, etc.